# NSURLRequest with UTF8 password

Tags: cocoa, nsurlconnection, basic-authentication, nsurlrequest, nsurlcredential

Here is a method I've written to connect to a server and get a user auth token:

```
+ (void)getAuthTokenForUsername:(NSString *)username
                       password:(NSString *)password
              completionHandler:(void (^)(NSString *, NSError *))completionHandler
{
    username = [username URLEncodedString];
    password = [password URLEncodedString];

    NSString *format = @"https://%@:%@@api.example.com/v1/user/api_token?format=json";
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:format, username, password];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL]
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *URLResponse, NSData *data, NSError *error)
    {
        NSString *token;
        if (data) {
            NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
            token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", username, dictionary[@"result"]];
        }
        completionHandler(token, error);
    }];
}
```

A URL then looks something like this: `https://username:hello%C2%B0@api.example.com/v1/user/api_token?format\=json`, where the password is `hello°`. The `URLEncodedString` method properly encodes everything as in the example, but the request never works. The problem is not with escaping or the server, because I can `curl` the same URL and I get nice JSON and authentication works, even though there is a non-ASCII character in the password. It also works from other programming languages like `ruby` or `python`. But the same url never works with `NSURLConnection` and it also doesn't work in Safari, which of course uses `NSURLConnection`. I get an 'The operation could not be completed' with a '401 Forbidden' every time.

(My code works fine when the password just contains ASCII characters. I also tried using the `NSURLCredential` methods, same problem.)

What do I need to do for `NSURLConnection` to work with such a URL as `https://username:hello%C2%B0@api.example.com/v1/user/api_token?format\=json` where the password contains non-ASCII characters?

Comment: What happens of you create the URL with the password as `hello°` instead of `hello%C2%B0`?

Comment: Then I get a "Bad URL" error.

Comment: What does the code for "`URLEncodedString`" look like?  It isn't an API supplied in NSString.  Did you put it in a category or?

Comment: Yes. It's a category method that loops through the chars of the string and escapes everything that needs to be escaped. I also tried using the CFString function, both get the job done, but the connection still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just performed several tests against my mockup server and I think I have a solution for you.

First of all, when you add username & password to an URL, they are not actually send to the server as part of the URL. They are sent as part of the `Authorization` header (see [Basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)).

The fastest workaround for you is to do

```
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
NSString* usernamePassword = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", username, password] base64Encode];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", usernamePassword] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"]
```

To understand the problem, let's go a bit deeper. Let's forget `NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:` and let us create an old-fashioned connection with a `NSURLConnectionDelegate`. Then in the delegate, let's define the following methods:

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return YES;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    NSLog(@"Proposal: %@ - %@", challenge.proposedCredential.user, challenge.proposedCredential.password);

    NSURLCredential* credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"username"    
                                                             password:@"hello°"
                                                          persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];

    [challenge.sender useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

If you don't create these methods, the username & password from your URL won't ever be added to the HTTP header.
If you add them, you'll see that the proposed password is `hello%C2%B0`. Obviously, that's wrong.

You can see the problem directly from

```
NSLog(@"Password: %@", [[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://username:hello%C2%B0@www.google.com"] password]);
```

which prints

```
hello%C2%B0
```

**I believe this is a bug in the framework**. `NSURL` returns `password` encoded and `NSURLCredential` doesn't decode it so we are left with an invalid password.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. One question: in your proposed workaround, do I escape the username and password and then base64-encode them, or do I base64-encode the unicode strings directly?

Comment: Base64-encode them directly. There is no need for URL escaping since you are not putting them into URL any more.

Comment: At last, I had a chance to try your proposed workaround. Everything works correctly. I don't think this is a known bug with `NSURLCredential`, I haven't seen it mentioned anywhere else.

Comment: @kmikael It's difficult to say what is known bug since Apple doesn't allow us to see current issues. I have just reported it.